# Can I exclude Microsoft.Data.OData languages ressources from build?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure

Azure Storage 2.0 client for c# use Microsoft.Data.OData library.
The problem is that at build i find in my build folder :

```
bin/de/Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll
bin/de/Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll
bin/de/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.resources.dll
bin/de/System.Spatial.resources.dll
bin/es/Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll
bin/es/Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll
bin/es/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.resources.dll
bin/es/System.Spatial.resources.dll
```

etc for languages de, es, fr, it, ja, ko, ru, zh twice

That makes around 3.2 Mo of I guess useless library in the package I send to Azure Cloud Instance. I like to have my packages the lightest possible to be sent quickly.

My application is set to work with Culture default and culture FR-FR

Is it safe to exclude all other language and HOW can I achieve this exclusion on build ?

Here is my webconfig

```
<runtime>
     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
     </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: You could always do a post build event and delete them, but I have no idea if they are required or not. Another option is to publish direct from source control and exclude the nuget package from your source control (will be added on build by the build server): http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/

Comment: This is a major pain, killing my publish time because it insists I upload Korean, Japanese etc. On the one hand, I wouldn't want to see all of these as different packages in NuGet, but on the other, I certainly don't want them all in my publish profile.

Comment: Why would MS add this libraries from the very beginning? In most cases this is just messing around with my deploy.

Answer (score 6):

One thing you could do is modify your `.csproj` file, hook into the `AfterBuild` event, and then delete the folders for all but the desired language. Not optimal, but it should work. Something like:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <DirsToClean Include="$(OutDir)\de;$(OutDir)\es;..." />
  </ItemGroup>
  <RemoveDir Directories="@(DirsToClean)" />
</Target>
```

As for whether it's safe to exclude... no idea. :)

Comment: This does work for the output of a website project. Too bas it doesn't work if the website is used as a web role in a cloud service project.

Comment: (worked using a WPF Project) this is a good workaround which neatly bypasses the forced binaries inclusion. Much easier than trying to mud-wrestle Nuget.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a approach that you can try.  The resources you are speaking of are a part of the solution and output because they are a part of referenced Nuget packages.  Specifically these:

- Microsoft.Data.OData 5.2.0
- Microsoft.Data.Edm 5.2.0
- System.Spatial 5.2.0

I'm not certain how relevant the versions are to this topic, but I created a new ASP.NET MVC 4.5 Web application and added Windows Azure Storage 2.0 package and they were installed as a result.

Now, there is an open source tool called Nuget Package Explorer: http://npe.codeplex.com/

With NPE, you can open, view, and edit Nuget packages.  You will find the folder containing these packages in the `packages` directory in the same relative path to where your solution is.

You need to edit the package with NPE and remove the references to the resource files there and save the package.  You will also need to delete the actual resource assemblies from the `packages` folder.

You should be able to perform a `Clean Solution...` and `Rebuild Solution` and see the software compile without those references.

This technique is essentially adjusting the configuration of your dependencies to affect the build output.